# Prevent a malicious user to fill my database by sign up a lot of accounts?

Tags: node.js, security, jwt

I am developping a REST API with node.JS. I saw a lot of tutorials to secure my API, especially with JWT Library, but I think about an issue to this process :

I need to ask to my users to signup sending to my server an id and a password that I can store in my database to generate a token for the following actions. But what if a malicious user wanted to add a lot of user to my database by sending to the URI of my server a lot of time informations to sign up a lot of time ?

Is there a way to prevent an "attack" like this ?

Is Auth0 can help me ?

Comment: OAuth doesn't deal with this type of issues. You could use a big identity provider (like facebook or google) who try to mitigate this  type of attack (to some extend)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something to limit or throttle requests made to your API endpoints. A good solution is to set up a middleware such as [`express-rate-limit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit).